# Use qualitative data to draw barplots

Tags: r, dataframe, bar-chart, transformation

I am looking for a solution to use this type of dataset which shows Sp (species) sampled in ForTyp (Forest types) and that have toxicotolerance (Toxitol, Nitrotol, Poustol) : N/A means no information in the dataset (a blank place):

```
dat<-read.table(text = "Sp     ForTyp     Toxitol     Nitrotol     Poustol
         A     1     y     y     N/A
         B     1     N/A     y     y
         C     1     y     y     N/A
         D     1     y     N/A     N/A
         E     2     y     N/A     N/A
         F     2     N/A     N/A     y
         A     3     y     y     N/A
         B     3     N/A     y     y
         C     3     y     y     N/A",header=T)
```

I am looking for a solution to transform the previous dataframe in :

```
dat2<-read.table(text = "ForTyp     Toxitol     Nitrotol     Poustol
     1     42,85     42,85     14,29
     2    50     0     50
     3    33,33     50     16,67", header=T)
```

This dataframe show the percentage of each columns (Toxitol, Nitrotol, Poustol) for the differents ForTyp (Forest types).
The aim is to be able to produce this type of graph :

[image: Toxicotolerance level showed by sampled species in the 3 different forest types]

Does someone have any idea for the data transformation and the barplots ?

Comment: how in the world do you get dat2 from dat?

Comment: Is the Sp irrelevant? I'm not seeing how it was used.

Comment: @rawr, after some thought, I figured it out. He's counting the number of `y`s of that column and then dividing by the total number of `y`s for each value of `ForTyp`. So for `ForTyp = 1`, there are 7 `y`s total, and 3 each for `Toxitol` and `Nitrotol` and 1 for `Poustol`. So 3/7, 3/7, 1/7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to go about it with the `plyr` package. Some work is needed on making the plot pretty, but the objective is achieved.

```
library(plyr)

dat[,3:5] <- ifelse(dat[,3:5] == "y",1,0)

dat2 <- ddply(.data = dat,.(ForTyp), .fun = function(x) {

  Toxitol = sum(x$Toxitol)

  Nitrotol = sum(x$Nitrotol)

  Poustol = sum(x$Poustol)

  props <- prop.table(c(Toxitol,Nitrotol,Poustol))

}

)

barplot(as.matrix( t( dat2[2:4] *100) ),names.arg = unique( dat[,2]),legend.text = colnames( dat[,3:5]))
```

[image]

Comment: Badger, many thanks, your solution do perfectly the job !
Cheers !

Comment: As an alternative, you could use `barplot` on `t(prop.table(rowsum((dat[3:5] == "y") + 0, dat[[2]]), margin = 1) * 100)`